# App does not respond while trying to access charsequence elements through a loop

Tags: java, android, charsequence

i m trying to make a calculator which can solve long expressions like 30+55-(2+7-20)

but i m having some logical problem in my equal button... beq

i have tested that logical problem is in for loop but couldnt understand. any help is greatl appreciated. heres my code

```
    beq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (status==1){
            get=tvdisp1.getText();                          //tvdisp1 represents textView top expression bar
    //      tvdisp2.setText(get);                           //tvdisp2 represents 2nd textView answer bar
            if(get.charAt(0)=='x') {status=0;}              //to check for syntax error
            if(get.charAt(0)=='÷') {status=0;}              // same

            for(int i =0; i <= get.length(); i++ ) {        // loop to check if the first character is digit or character.
                if (Character.isDigit(get.charAt(i))) {
                    //is digit
                } 
                else {
                    //is operator

                }
            }

            if (cbracq_c>obracs_c){status=0;}               // if number of closing brackets > opening brackets
            if ( status == 0 ) { tvdisp1.setText("Syntax Error AC to reset");}
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your loop will throw an exception, as you're using `<=` instead of `<`.

Comment: oh u mean i  am accessing array(charSequence) unauthorized??

Comment: It's not a matter of "unauthorized" - it's a matter of going out of bounds. But you should be seeing the exception in your log...

Answer (score 2):

it is just as Jon Skeet said.
You count 1 to far -> get.length() gives u a length (for example) 5, so you have index from 0 to 4. But in your loop you are also try to access index 5 because of the "<**=**". Just change it to "<" and it should work

Comment: May this link is what you are looking for: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t141739-max-length-of-a-string.html